Bribery and corruption has or have

Bribery and corruption has become the part of the society.


Bribery and corruption have become the part of the society.

In these examples, we will take bribery and corruption either as singular or as plural. How can it be understood whether two nouns connected with 'and' work as one unit or they stand separately.

Both singular and plural are possible.
The first the should be removed:

Bribery and corruption have become part of the society.

This chart shows the plural to be more common.
Generally, the plurality of a pair of nouns
depends on how closely related they are; the closer the relationship is, the higher the chance of the pair being considered as one.

Also, the OP uses nouns in the pattern "X and Y are Z." This can work, and happens often, and it's just fine for Z to be singular even though the subject was plural... as long as Z has a meaning that allows it. "Abbott and Costello are a team": yes, but "Abbott and Costello are a comedian": no.

Thanks, @Andy Bonner.   Yes, the grammatical number of a subject complement can be different from its subject's.
